# PHP VK API выгрузка товаров в группу

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Использую PHP SDK.
Проблема в следующем.
При выгрузке товаров в цикле(примерно 2000 товаров), когда скрипт доходит до метода

```
vk->photos()->saveMarketPhoto()
```

появляется ошибка

```
One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: photo is undefined (100)
```

Ошибка может появляться на разных товарах. Один раз может на одном товаре, а в следующий раз данный товар будет выгружен, а ошибка может возникнуть через 10-20 итераций. Также заметил, что если выгружать 500 товаров то ошибка появляется реже.
Изображение загружается используя CURL и в том случае когда появляется данная ошибка, то в в ответе от сервера приходит следующее сообщение

```
[error] => ERR_UPLOAD_ORIGINAL_NOT_FOUND: max size photo file not found  
[bwact] => do_add  
[server] => ---  
[_sig] => ---
```

хотя все параметры для загрузки(ссылка откуда загружать изображения, id сервера, т.д.) указаны корректно.
Пробовал увеличить время задержки между итерациями загрузки, не особо помогло. Методы вызываются с задержкой в 1 секунду.
Может кто-нибудь подсказать в чем проблема? Какие-то ограничения на обращение к API или еще что?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Проблему помогла решить поддержка в ВК.
Решение следующее.
Отловить, когда от сервера возвращается

```
[error] => ERR_UPLOAD_ORIGINAL_NOT_FOUND: max size photo file not found
```

и в случае ошибки еще раз вызвать метод

```
photos()->getMarketUploadServer()
```

Получить новый id сервера и уже на него загрузить изображение через CURL.